# Energy Monitor Install load center phase connection

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, home-automation

In an attempt to ensure accurate electrical load center phase connection for a neurio home energy monitor, the installation video around [2:40](https://youtu.be/ky8vmwRFGuk?t=2m41s) mentions connecting to the red wire to another Phase "let's call it, Phase B" then mentions "every other breaker is on a different phase" with a A B A B diagram for each (tandem) breaker. Per the install diagram on the install video, is it safe to assume the red wire is on a the fourth breaker from the left top, if the first black wire is connected to the leftmost top breaker?

A more pertainant question in my case, per my load center, image below, the second breaker from the top left is on a separate phase from the top tandem breaker, in this two phase load center?

Is there any relevant recommended general industry encyclopedia type resource for this?﻿

The neutral bus bar has white wires connected to it, and the ground bar has the no insulation on the wiring?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: [Neurio_W1_Quick_Install_Guide_-_2_phase.pdf](http://support.neur.io/customer/en/portal/articles/1847878-neurio-quick-install-guides) came with the unit.

Comment: [Wiring question seems accurate enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring)

Comment: This looks like a sub panel fed from the 50amp double pole breaker since I don't see another feed. All double pole breakers are on L1+ L2 . I hope the breaker is rated for back feed not to say it would not work correctly but may cause inspection issues or need to be replaced with a really sharp home inspection prior to a refinance or sale.

Comment: @EdBeal -- the backfeed rating can be assumed unless the breaker is marked as having Line and Load terminals on it

Comment: I would agree but in my state they have to be listed for back feed. I have failed an inspection in the past for this and now I just spend a few more bucks and get a panel with a main.

Comment: @EdBeal -- *weird* -- my understanding is that breakers are listed for backfeed unless labeled otherwise

Comment: See [this doc](http://static.schneider-electric.us/docs/Circuit%20Protection/0900DB1001.pdf) for details btw

Comment: @edbeal If the power source, a home panel, from this rv, is an "on end", it doesn't need a special breaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This explanation](https://youtu.be/J6Q4JrCpRVk?t=5m40s) is sufficient, the second breaker is on a separate phase.